# Division en Java no da bien resultado

Tags: java, matemáticas

Funciona si ingreso 10 y luego 2, me da 5.
Pero la estoy aplicando en otro programa y ahora suelta para probar y no me da los resultados que tiene decimales es decir la división de `2/10` que seria `0.2` no me lo muestra.

¿Por que? ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduce dos numeros para dividir\nNumero: ");
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Numero: ");
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();
    float div = num1/num2;
    System.out.println("La division de "+num1+"/"+num2+" = " +div);
}
```

Comment: Has probado a buscaqar un formateador (formatter) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Lo que sucede que si divides dos números enteros el resultado será otro número entero.**

Es por eso que se debe hacer el cast de cualquier valor entero a dividir a uno de tipo `float` ya que el **cast se realiza antes de la operación**.

El resultado de la operación entre un número entero y uno de tipo `float`  será un `float`, antes de asignar el valor a la variable `div`.

```
2/10 = 0.2 /* Pero como retorna un entero devuelve el 0 */
float div = (float) num1/num2; /* retorna 0.2*/
```

Answer (score 5):

Este codigo te permite realizar la división entre decimales , ya que las 
   variables  las declare double lo cual me permite realizar divisiones y que el 
   resultado me de decimal

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Introduce dos numeros para dividir\nNumero: ");
double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Numero: ");
double num2 = sc.nextDouble();
double div = num1/num2;
System.out.println("La division de "+num1+"/"+num2+" = " +div);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tienes de dos opciones:

1. Cambiar tus tipos de datos que tomas del `Scanner` de `int` a `float`, esto porque cuando divides dos enteros el resultado será otro número entero, dejando tus variables así:

   ```
   float num1 = sc.nextFloat();
   float num2 = sc.nextFloat();
   ```
2. Castear tu operación al punto que requieres, en este caso punto flotante, por lo que tu variable `div` quedaría así:

   ```
   float div = (float) (num1 / num2) ;
   ```

Comment: La segunda opción no es válida: primero se haría la división entera y luego se convierte a float. Por ejemplo, si tomamos 9 y 2, el resultado de la división entera es 4, luego se convierte a float y tenemos 4.0.
Con la primera opción, 9 y 2 se convertirían a 9.0 y 2.0, por lo que la división sería real: 4.5