# Java aritmética con valores de tipo INT

Tags: java

```
public class Joyanes650 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double pi;

        pi=2*(2/4)*(2/3)*(4/3)*(4/5);

        System.out.println(pi);
    }

}
```

El programa imprime: `0.0`.
La respuesta en una calculadora normal es `0.7111`.
¿Por qué no me da la respuesta correcta en java?
¿Cual sería la forma correcta de hacer ese ejercicio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando efectuas operaciones aritméticas con 2 valores de tipo `int`, el resultado debe ser de tipo `int`. De modo que si el resultado incluye una fracción, la fracción es eliminada para que el resultado pueda respectar la regla de que debe ser de tipo `int`.

Por ejemplo, cuando tu programa calcula `2/4`, aunque esperarías que el resultado fuera `0.5`, lo cierto es que para que el resultado respete el tipo `int`, el resultado es convertido a `0`.

De forma similar, con `4/3`, el resultado es `1` en vez de `1.3333333`.

Para evitar este problema, es necesario que al menos uno de los 2 valores que participan en la aritmética sea de tipo `float` o `double` en vez de `int`.

Una manera de lograr esto es haciendo un cast:

```
(float)4/3
```

Pero en tu caso, lo más sencillo es de simplemente agragar un `.0` al final de tus valores. Hacer esto cambia el tipo de `int` a `double`:

```
pi=2.0*(2.0/4.0)*(2.0/3.0)*(4.0/3.0)*(4.0/5.0);
```

Comment: mil gracias... que buena explicación

Answer (score 0):

revisa este mismo post. donde consultan lo mismo. puedes aclarar tus dudas ;)

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66373/division-en-java-no-da-bien-resultado)

como indica el compañero puedes realizar lo siguiente.

```
pi=(double)2*((double)2/4)*((double)2/3)*((double)4/3)*((double)4/5);
```

o

```
pi=2.0*(2.0/4.0)*(2.0/3.0)*(4.0/3.0)*(4.0/5.0);
```