# Redondear con Math.round en JAVA

Tags: java

En páginas he visto que se puede redondear, dejando dos decimales usando el método `Math.round` de la siguiente manera:

```
System.out.println(Math.round(2.8049999999999997 * 100) / 100d);
```

Entiendo que la `d` de `100d` hace referencia a un `Double`. De esta manera imprime un número con dos decimales, pero sin la `d` imprime un número entero. Aunque sé que existe otras muchas opciones, quiero entender por qué sucede esto.

¿Podría alguien explicarme?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Java aritmética con valores de tipo INT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117458/java-aritm%c3%a9tica-con-valores-de-tipo-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `Math.round` devuelve un número entero y en java al dividir un número entero entre otro número entero el resultado devuelve también un número entero.

Ej: `Math.round(2.8049999999999997 * 100) / 100 => 281 / 100 => 2`

Esto se hace ya que puede que en algún momento desees obtener el resto de dicha operación usando % en vez de /.

Ej: `Math.round(2.8049999999999997 * 100) % 100 => 281 % 100 => 81`

Entonces cuando conviertes el 100 en un decimal ya no estás realizando una división entre enteros, por lo que java también operará sobre el resto de dicha división hasta los dos decimales.

Ej: `Math.round(2.8049999999999997 * 100) / 100d => 281 / 100.00 => 2.81`

Espero haber aclarado tus dudas :)